# Combine multiple API calls into one result

Tags: excel, rest, powerquery

I'm using an API (for a project management database) that returns a result in the following form (in PQ format):

```
[
    Content =
    [
        Projects = {"project1", "project2", "project3", "project4"},
        InvoiceGroups = {"group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"},
        Phases = {"phase1", "phase2", "phase3", "phase4"},
        Resources = {"resource1", "resource2", "resource3", "resource4"},
    ]
]
```

NOTE: in reality there are tens of thousands of entries in each of these inner/nested lists; and each entry is actually not a string but a Power Query record.

The API limits the database request to about 2000 projects at a time, so I have to break the request up into chunks. So instead of getting a single PQ record back with the entire response, I am getting multiple of them in a list.

So I have something like this, which is a list of PQ list of PQ records:

```
{
    [
        Content =
        [
            Projects = {"project1"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group1"},
            Phases = {"phase1"},
            Resources = {"resource1"},
        ]
    ],
    [
        Content =
        [
            Projects = {"project2"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group2"},
            Phases = {"phase2"},
            Resources = {"resource2"},
        ]
    ],
    [
        Content =
        [
            Projects = {"project3"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group3"},
            Phases = {"phase3"},
            Resources = {"resource3"},
        ]
    ],
    [
        Content =
        [
            Projects = {"project4"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group4"},
            Phases = {"phase4"},
            Resources = {"resource4"},
        ]
    ],
}
```

My question is: how can I write an efficient Power Query function to recombine these separate responses back into the original response, with the nested lists recombined the way they should be?

I attempted just using the [`Record.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/record-combine) function, but it does not work:

```
let
    recombined = Record.Combine(list_of_records)
in
    recombined
```

(NOTE: I'd prefer to do this in Python but for reasons I won't go into, we do need to do this in PQ.)

Comment: @horseyride I didn't think that people trying to help will not be able to copy and paste it! I'll fix it. :) Sorry.

Comment: @horseyride fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You can process your `Content` *(which is a Power Query record and not a valid JSON)* like this:

```
let
    Content =
        [
            Projects = {"project1", "project2", "project3", "project4"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"},
            Phases = {"phase1", "phase2", "phase3", "phase4"},
            Resources = {"resource1", "resource2", "resource3", "resource4"}
        ],
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Content),

    #"Expand Values" = Table.FromColumns(
        #"Converted to Table"[Value],
        #"Converted to Table"[Name]),
        
    #"Set Data Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expand Values", 
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expand Values"), each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Set Data Type"
```

***From Your Data***
[image]

***I'm not sure what else you are looking for, though***
 If you have multiple returns like this, you could probably incorporate the above into a function, and apply it to each of the data downloads, then combine the tables. If something else, you will need to be more specific.

***Note:*** Referencing your comment in which you want to convert to a table only after you have all of the data records downloaded, you could use the following algorithm, although I don't know if it will be any more efficient.

The first step is to download all the data and put it into a list. Then run the code below the `#"All Content"` step

```
let
    Content1 =
        [
            Projects = {"project1", "project2", "project3", "project4"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"},
            Phases = {"phase1", "phase2", "phase3", "phase4"},
            Resources = {"resource1", "resource2", "resource3", "resource4"}
        ],
    Content2 =
        [
            Projects = {"project1", "project2", "project3", "project4"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"},
            Phases = {"phase1", "phase2", "phase3", "phase4"},
            Resources = {"resource1", "resource2", "resource3", "resource4"}
        ],

//Start here with a List of all the records        
    #"All Content" = {Content1,Content2},
   
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"All Content", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Projects", "InvoiceGroups", "Phases", "Resources"}),

#"Expand Lists" =
    Table.FromColumns(
        List.Accumulate(
            Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Column"),
            {},
            (s,c)=> s & {List.Combine(Table.Column(#"Expanded Column",c))}),
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Column")),

    #"Set Data Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expand Lists", List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expand Lists"), each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Set Data Types"
```

***Result***
[image]

Or, given your multi-Record list from your question, *corrected to remove errant commas*:

```
let 
    #"All Content" =
    {
    [
        Content =
        [
            Projects = {"project1"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group1"},
            Phases = {"phase1"},
            Resources = {"resource1"}
        ]
    ],
    [
        Content =
        [
            Projects = {"project2"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group2"},
            Phases = {"phase2"},
            Resources = {"resource2"}
        ]
    ],
    [
        Content =
        [
            Projects = {"project3"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group3"},
            Phases = {"phase3"},
            Resources = {"resource3"}
        ]
    ],
    [
        Content =
        [
            Projects = {"project4"},
            InvoiceGroups = {"group4"},
            Phases = {"phase4"},
            Resources = {"resource4"}
        ]
    ]
    },
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"All Content", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Content"}),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Content", {"Projects", "InvoiceGroups", "Phases", "Resources"}),

#"Expand Lists" =
    Table.FromColumns(
        List.Accumulate(
            Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Content"),
            {},
            (s,c)=> s & {List.Combine(Table.Column(#"Expanded Content",c))}),
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Content")),

    #"Set Data Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expand Lists", List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expand Lists"), each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Set Data Types"
```

[image]

Comment: Ok: what I was asking for is help writing a function, that combines the list of responses into a single response, which I was then going to turn into a table. However your suggestion of converting each response into a table first, and then combining the tables, is another way of doing it. I don't love it, but it would work. Thanks!

Comment: @Rick See **Note** in edited answer for a method of combining a *List* of your *Records*. You can create that list in many ways, depending on your data source. `List.Generate` or `List.Accumulate` are commonly used for that purpose. By the way, if my answer is what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).